# Performing operations on multiple subsets within a data.frame (R)

Tags: r

Given the following sample dataset:

```
    df<-data.frame(year=c("1990","1990","1990","1991","1991","1991","1992","1992","1992"), C2=LETTERS[1:3], C3=rnorm(1:9)) 
    df
      year C2           C3
    1 1990  A -0.973627230
    2 1990  B -0.755867016
    3 1990  C  0.016505689
    4 1991  A -0.004353502
    5 1991  B  0.525895816
    6 1991  C -0.882487930
    7 1992  A -0.206509950
    8 1992  B  0.192527583
    9 1992  C  0.935712021
```

Is there a way I can do the following for each unique value of `year`:

add the values of `C3` when `C2 == B` and `C2 == C`, then divide by the value of `C3` when `C2==A`?

So, for each `year`, I get a value for `(B+C)/A`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use *data.table*.  Just write the code out exactly as you explain it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, sum(C3[C2 %in% c("B", "C")]) / C3[C2 == "A"], by = year]
#    year          V1
# 1: 1990 -0.08157762
# 2: 1991  4.44625385
# 3: 1992 13.03606921
```

If *dplyr*'s your bag, then here it is done in *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, year) %>%
    summarise(out = sum(C3[C2 %in% c("B", "C")]) / C3[C2 == "A"])
```

Comment: Dang, and here I was messing around with loops and if statements all day. Thanks!